# Two tables and two columns extraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

What is the problem?

```
INSERT INTO [database].table1 (Number)
    SELECT sd.a1 - sd.b1 AS kalan  
    FROM NUMBERS sd
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'code', table 'database.dbo.table1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: The value, which you try to insert is NULL. So, set the value to a valid value and the problem is solved. Or allow the column to contain NULL.

Comment: When one (or both) of the columns in the difference is `NULL`, that difference will also be `NULL`, and you'll see the error.  What do you want to happen when one (or both) values are `NULL`?

Comment: Well, the error is **very clear**: your table `table1` has a column `code` which **cannot** be NULL - but you're not providing any value for that column in your `INSERT` statement - that's the root cause of the error. How to fix it? You need to **provide a value** for `code` - plain and simple

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all columns which are not allowed `null` values  :

```
INSERT INTO [database].table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)  --- Columns which are not allowd null values
      SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
      FROM Table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the column is an IDENTITY column or if it has ISNULL constraint enebled.

```
 INSERT INTO [database].table1 (code)
 SELECT  sd.a1 - sd.b1 AS kalan  FROM  NUMBERS sd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL` to convert `null` to `0`

```
INSERT INTO [database].table1 (Number)
SELECT ISNULL((sd.a1 - sd.b1),0) AS kalan  
FROM NUMBERS sd
```

Comment: marc_s has given the correct answer in his comment: A column "Number" is being inserted, but the table also has a column "code" which can't be null.

Comment: Thank You very much